# Does a submersible well pump need an electrical disconnect?

Tags: electrical, well-pump

I recently had a well installed for an irrigation system.  I had a few electricians come over to give quotes.  One of which suggested I needed a quick disconnect switch. While another says its not needed.  Google isn't helping me come to a good conclusion regarding this.

What should be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Submersible is one of the specific exceptions ("impractical or causes increased hazard") to "disconnect in sight required." However, the disconnect means should have provision to be locked in the open ("off") position, and that locking means needs to remain in place whether or not a lock is installed.

430.102 is the code section in question.